# Obtener el valor de una propiedad de un control dentro de otro en C# - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

tengo varios botones similares pero que el text que se muestra es diferente, esto lo hago con un botón y dentro con un textblock y una imagen.  Lo que necesito es reconocer cual fue el botón que se seleccionó y mostrarlo en un label aparte, por ejemplo.
el código xaml es:

```
<Button  Margin="3" MinHeight="50" Click="Button_Click">
       <TextBlock Text="Ciudad 1" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
   </Button>

   <Button Margin="3" MinHeight="50" Click="Button_Click">
      <TextBlock Text="Ciudad 2" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
   </Button>
```

y el codigo del boton sería:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string ciudad;
        Button botonActual = (Button)sender;
        ciudad = botonActual.Content.ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(ciudad);
    }
```

Pero me devuelve "System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock" y la idea es que devuelva el contenido del texto, en este caso, debería ser "Ciudad 1" o "Ciudad 2" dependiendo el botón.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda
Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas declarar un `TextBlock` dentro del `Button` porque el `Button` ya tiene un `TextBlock` dentro, simplemente pon el nombre de la ciudad en el `Content` del `Button`, así:

```
<Button Content="Ciudad 1" Margin="3" MinHeight="50" Click="Button_Click"/>
<Button Content="Ciudad 2" Margin="3" MinHeight="50" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Y listo, luego en el evento `Click` obtienes el texto llamando a la misma propiedad, así:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string ciudad;
    Button botonActual = (Button)sender;
    ciudad = botonActual.Content;
    
    MessageBox.Show(ciudad);
}
```

o lo que es igual

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((Button)sender).Content);
}
```

Nada más que eso.

**EDIT:**

Para obtener lo que hay dentro del `Button`, se usa `Content`, esta propiedad puede ser, como ya sabes, cualquier cosa, un `TextBlock`, una `Imagen`, un `Rectangle`, etc. Y solo necesitas decirle al compilador que trate ese `Content` como lo que es, anteponiendo el tipo de dato que corresponde

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tx = (TextBlock)((Button)sender).Content;
    MessageBox.Show(tx.Text);
}
```

Ahora bien, `Content` solo puede ser 1 elemento hijo, pero si necesitas tener más de 1 lo puedes meter todo dentro de un `Grid` o un `Border`, y luego ejecutas la misma operación para obtener sus datos.

```
<Button >
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Tx1" Text="Texto 1"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Tx2" Text="Texto 2"/>
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

Y la operación sería algo así:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = (Grid)((Button)sender).Content;
    UIElementCollection hijos = grid.Children;
    TextBlock text1 = (TextBlock)hijos[0];
    TextBlock text2 = (TextBlock)hijos[1];
    
    MessageBox.Show(text1 + " " + text2);
}
```

Solo recuerda anteponer el tipo de dato que sabes que hay dentro del `Button` y listo, usas `Children` para saber que hay dentro de los controles de tipo contenedor como `Grid` o `StackPanel` y usa `Parent` para saber qué control es el padre otro control.

Y si no estás seguro de qué cosa hay dentro de un botón lo puedes comparar así:

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = (Grid)((Button)sender).Content;
    UIElementCollection hijos = grid.Children;
    
    if(hijos[0].GetType() == typeof(TextBlock))
    {
        TextBlock text1 = (TextBlock)hijos[0];
        MessageBox.Show(text1.Text);
    }
}
```

Y eso es todo.
Suerte.

Comment: Gracias Leodev por tu comentario, aunque lo coloco con el textblock dentro ya que quiero colocar una imagen y adicional el texto en "wrap" ya que algunos textos son más largos y con el botón solo no me da esas opciones

Comment: En ese caso basta con obtener el Content, y convertirlo en el tipo de control que tu quieres, modificaré la respuesta.